# Finish setting up your AOSP on Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting this message ["You can finish setting up your AOSP on IA Emulator soon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YSJ7.png)on my Android Studio Emulator when i click over wifi settings, and i can't connect the emulator to internet. How can i fix it? or what did i miss?

Comment: I'll add this as a comment, since I don't know if this will solve your issue. I had to restart the device, and set the DNS in the Network preferences (I was using a Mac)